# ui-grid export pdf column get cut

Tags: angular, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I use ui-grid export pdf , but the last column always get cut in half. No matter what page size I set.

I search around, some one said, set exporterPdfOrientation: 'landscape',
at

```
 $scope.gridOptions = { ...  exporterPdfOrientation: 'landscape', ...}
```

It does not work for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After many try:  I found the solution is decrease exporterPdfMaxGridWidth: 600,

[exporterPdf configuration source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/e30596b/src/features/exporter/js/exporter.js#L31)

[exporterPdf pagesize](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/master/src/standardPageSizes.js)

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
    exporterPdfOrientation: 'landscape',
     exporterPdfPageSize:'A4',  // exporterPdfMaxGridWidth = Defaults to 720 (for A4 landscape), use 670 for LETTER
    // page size see --- https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/master/src/standardPageSizes.js

   exporterPdfMaxGridWidth: 600,    // bug, for A4, default is 720, set to 600 solve my problem.
```

here is result, no more cut column
[image]